# Unable to delete characters from active cell in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel 2013 worksheet that has some data that is in HTML format (in particular, subscript and superscript).  I am trying to reformat the data appropriately.  As I loop through each cell, I run a macro to format the HTML and strip out the tags. For the first cell, it works just fine.  For the second cell, I get this error: ""

Any ideas on what is going on?

'This cell works just fine - it turns the o character to superscript and strips out the tags

```
10) Using the above graphic, what is the temperature at point A?
A. 2<sup>o</sup> C
B. 4<sup>o</sup> C
C. 5<sup>o</sup> C
D. 7<sup>o</sup> C
```

'This cell throws the exception

```
43) Which is true for all Mesothermal (C) climates?
A. The wamest month is between 10 and 18<sup>o</sup>C
B. The warmest month is greater than 10<sup>o</sup>C and the coldest month is between 0 and 10<sup>o</sup>C
C. The coldest month is below 0<sup>o</sup>C
D. All of the above
```

Here's the macro code:

```
Sub FormatHTML(inval As Variant)
    Dim outval As String
    Dim isSup As Boolean
    Dim isSub As Boolean
    Dim start As Integer
    Dim start2 As Integer

    isSup = InStr(ActiveCell.Value, "<sup>") > 0
    isSub = InStr(ActiveCell.Value, "<sub>") > 0

    Do Until isSup = False And isSub = False
        If isSup Then
            start = InStr(ActiveCell.Value, "<sup>") + 5
            With ActiveCell.Characters(start:=start, Length:=1).Font
                .Superscript = True
            End With
            With ActiveCell.Characters(start:=(start - 5), Length:=5)
                .Delete
            End With
            start2 = InStr(ActiveCell.Value, "</sup>")
            With ActiveCell.Characters(start:=start2, Length:=6)
                .Delete
            End With
        End If
        If isSub Then
            start = InStr(ActiveCell.Value, "<sub>") + 5
            With ActiveCell.Characters(start:=start, Length:=1).Font
                .Subscript = True
            End With
            With ActiveCell.Characters(start:=(start - 5), Length:=5)
                .Delete
            End With
            start2 = InStr(ActiveCell.Value, "</sub>")
            With ActiveCell.Characters(start:=start2, Length:=6)
                .Delete
            End With
        End If
        isSup = InStr(ActiveCell.Value, "<sup>") > 0
        isSub = InStr(ActiveCell.Value, "<sub>") > 0
    Loop
End Sub
```

Thanks,
Glenn

Comment: The reason is because your loop isn't actually looping.  You're using `ActiveCell` and as far as I can tell, the activecell never changes.  That's why it's only happening once. Edit: Hm, I think I misread.  Are you running the macro individually (i.e. are you manually selecting a cell, then running the macro)?  Also, what does the error say when it occurs?

Comment: Sorry, I am an idiot - here is the error: 
Run-time error '1004'
Delete method of Characters class failed

And if wasn't exactly clear - As I loop through each cell, I set the cell to to be the active cell.  The FormatHTML process loops through the cell contents, and does the work.  The first cell in my example works fine, but the second throws the error.  I have no idea why.

Comment: Haha, nah, it happens! Do you need help to loop this macro, or do you know how to get started?

Comment: I did notice in debugging the second cell, it makes the first superscript change and then fails on the .Delete call of the <sup> tag.  Not sure why, since it worked just fine for all the <sup> tags in the first cell.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of some sample data, so I can recreate your data and try it on my comp?

Comment: Apparently, as a newbie, I don't have enough reputation points to post an image.  If you take the two snippets from my original post, you can paste them into the formula bar in excel and try.

Comment: Quick question - it looks like the main point isn't necessarily removing HTML, but fixing the degree symbol/super and subscript.  Is that correct, or is there other parts of this that will deal with other HTML things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing more (such as, will you be using this for other HTML tags, or just the superscript?), the following removes `<sup>o</sup>` and replaces with the degree symbol:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range

    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1))

    rng.Replace What:="<sup>o</sup>", Replacement:="°", LookAt:=xlPart _
        , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

You can also do the same with `<sub>`, just copy the `rng.Replace ...` and use `<sub>` instead of `<sup>`.  Does this work, or is there more HTML you need removed, etc?

Edit: Ok, the **issue is that `.Characters.Delete` can't be used on cells more than 255 characters**.  So, what I'm trying to do is to, if the cell length > 255, split into two cells and tackle one at a time.  This still needs tweaking, but I figured I'd put what I have now:

```
Sub FormatHTML()
Dim outval  As String
Dim isSup As Boolean, isSub As Boolean
Dim start As Integer, start2 As Integer, lastRow As Integer, i As Integer
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range

isSup = InStr(ActiveCell.Value, "<sup>") > 0
isSub = InStr(ActiveCell.Value, "<sub>") > 0

Set cel = ActiveCell

lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 2))

For Each cel In rng

    If Len(cel) > 255 Then
        cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = Right(cel.Value, Len(cel.Value) - 255)
        cel.Value = Left(cel.Value, 255)
        isSup = InStr(cel.Value, "<sup>") > 0
        isSub = InStr(cel.Value, "<sub>") > 0

    End If
    Do Until isSup = False And isSub = False
        If isSup Then
            start = InStr(cel.Value, "<sup>") + 5
            With cel.Characters(start:=start, Length:=1).Font
                .Superscript = True
            End With
            With cel.Characters(start:=(start - 5), Length:=5)
                .Delete
            End With
            start2 = InStr(cel.Value, "</sup>")
            With cel.Characters(start:=start2, Length:=6)
                .Delete
            End With
        End If
        If isSub Then
            start = InStr(cel.Value, "<sub>") + 5
            With cel.Characters(start:=start, Length:=1).Font
                .Subscript = True
            End With
            With cel.Characters(start:=(start - 5), Length:=5)
                .Delete
            End With
            start2 = InStr(cel.Value, "</sub>")
            With cel.Characters(start:=start2, Length:=6)
                .Delete
            End With
        End If
        isSup = InStr(cel.Value, "<sup>") > 0
        isSub = InStr(cel.Value, "<sub>") > 0
    Loop
Next cel

For i = 2 To lastRow
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2)) Then
        Cells(i, 2).Offset(0, -1).Value = Cells(i, 2).Offset(0, -1).Value & Cells(i, 2).Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Edit2: A couple notes.  As you can tell with the above, it will separate cells with len > 255 into two cells.  It then tries to add the second cell text back to COl. A.  *However, problem:* when you combine the text from the second cell with the first, the Degree Symbols get reset to `o` instead of superscripted.

A couple workarounds exist.  One is to use Find/Replace (as I put at the top), and as you have new HTML elements to replace, just add to this list.  Or, you can run your sub for all cells that are under 255 in Length, and separate the larger cells yourself. (Note that the code, as of now, will split `</sup>` into `</su` and `p>` if the length at the end > 255...I'll keep working to see if there's a better solution.

Comment: There are some <sub> calls, as well as some instances where the character in the tag is a 2 or a 3, rather than o.  The part that I can't get over is why the first cell gets formatted correctly, but the second one doesn't.  Oh well, it's something to try.

Comment: Aha! I figured out why - `.Characters.delete` apparently only works in cells less than 255 characters.  We would have to break up any cells with more than that, then recombine.

Comment: Looks like breaking them up did the trick.  Now I just have to figure out the best way to concatenate them back together.  But that's a problem for a different day.

Comment: +1 for finding to 255 limit issue! I think @GOG_Prof should just use your initial answer (`rng.Replace What:="<sup>o</sup>", Replacement:="°"...`) instead of working around the limitation

Comment: It would have worked but I ran into trouble getting a subscript 2 character.  I tried +1'ing, but apparently, I don't have enough reputation points for that either.

Comment: I should hopefully get something better tomorrow, FYI.

Comment: @GOG_Prof - quick question - do you need the question, and ABCD choices all in the same cell? Or is it okay if the Question is in Row 1, "A" is Row 2, "B" is Row 3, etc.?